# Android camera and SurfaceView not working

Tags: java, android, camera, hardware, surfaceview

I'm getting this weird error in my code
[image: a]

Cannot resolve symbol 'surfaceCallback'

theese are my current imports

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: post your logcat error here.

Comment: I haven't run the code yet, since i can't compile it with this error :(

Comment: have u implement surfacecall back interface

Answer (score 0):

implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`   on your Activity and pass `this` in `addCallBack();`

Answer (score 0):

`SurfaceHolder.Callback` is related to its Surface.

Abstract interface to someone holding a display surface. Allows you to control the surface size and format, edit the pixels in the surface, and monitor changes to the surface. This interface is typically available through the `SurfaceView` class.

When using this interface from a thread other than the one running its `SurfaceView`, you will want to carefully read the methods `lockCanvas()` and `Callback.surfaceCreated()`.

You need to implement the `SurfaceCallback` interface of `SurfaceView` as below:

```
public class callbackSurfaceMethod implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
  @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Change in your code.

```
surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(callbackSurfaceMethod );
```

Comment: but i am already implementing 'ActionBar.OnNavigationListener'

Comment: Its related to `SurfaceView` not `ActionBar`

Comment: i know. but you can't implement more than one libary

Comment: Its not library its an interface.

Comment: but i'm still unable to implement it

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```